# Why doesn't the whole image fit into the block?

Tags: html, css, owl-carousel

There is a block that occupies 50% of the screen width and in this block there is an owl-carousel with a slide of pictures, but the pictures are not completely placed there, given that the block is a square with equal width and height.
How to make the image fit without cropping to the block size and fit completely into the block?
Maybe this has something to do with the owl-carousel feature?

```css
.stucco-gal {
  width: 50%;
}

.img {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}

.pbg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery stucco-gal">
  <div class="owl-carousel">
    <div class="img">
      <div class="pbg" style="background-image: url(img/bg-1.jpg);"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="img">
      <div class="pbg" style="background-image: url(img/bg-6.jpg);"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="img">
      <div class="pbg" style="background-image: url(img/bg-7.jpg);"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="img">
      <div class="pbg" style="background-image: url(img/bg-8.jpg);"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you try with IMG width and height set to auto?

Comment: Please have a look at object-fit property [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit).

Answer (score 0):

You can change your `background-size: cover;` to `contain`

`cover` covers the area
`contain` adjusts the image (without cropping it) to the area

Alternatively, you may go a different route and use object-fit: contain:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

I also noticed, the way you're calling your image, the default setting for `background-repeat` is `repeat`, so, try adding:

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/pr_background-repeat.asp